# C++ set value changed suddenly after erasing?

Tags: c++, set, erase

I couldn't figure out why the integer number changed suddenly. If it is due to the erase, then shouldn't it happen right after I erase it? Then it would be caused by manipulating the houses array `houses[a[*j].household_id].agent_id.insert(i);`? But this didn't modify `*j` or `family_set[2]`. I'm confused....

```
class env
{
   set<int> agent_id;
}
class agent
{
   int household_id;
}

unordered_set<int> *family_set=new unordered_set<int>[4];
....
family_set[2].insert(12472);
....
env **houses=new env*[no_area];
agent **agents=new agent*[no_area];
for(int j=0;j<no_area;j++)
{
   houses[i]=new env[j];
   agents[j]=new agent[population[j]];
}

auto j=family_set[2].begin();
cout<<*j<<endl;
family_set[2].erase(*j);
cout<<*j<<endl;
houses[a[*j].household_id].agent_id.insert(i);
cout<<*j<<endl;
```

Output:

```
12472
12472
6505440
```

I tried to erase *j at the very end, this doesn't happen....

```
    auto j=family_set[2].begin();
    cout<<*j<<endl;
    houses[a[*j].household_id].agent_id.insert(i);
    cout<<*j<<endl;
    family_set[2].erase(*j);
    cout<<*j<<endl;
```

Output:

```
12472
12472
12472
```

Does this mean that the `*j` gets erased not instantly, but sometime later it will eventually gets become a random number?

Comment: This question's shown code does not meet stackoverflow.com's requirements for a [mre]. This means it's unlikely that anyone here can conclusively answer the question; but only guess at the most. You should [edit] your question to show a minimal example, no more than one or two pages of code (the "minimal" part), that everyone else can cut/paste, compile, run, and reproduce the described issue (the "reproducible" part) ***exactly as shown*** (this includes any ancillary information, like the input to the program). See [ask] for more information.

Comment: Also, if the code compiles, please try to use a debugger first :)

Comment: You would do well to check out the invalidation rules for `erase` and `insert`.

Comment: How about adding a [mre]? Can you answer the following question: can everyone cut/paste ***exactly what's shown***, compile, and reproduce the results. Unless you can answer "yes", this is not a [mre].

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/erase) for `std::set::erase()`:

> References and iterators to the erased elements are invalidated. Other references and iterators are not affected.